# Partial Rendering with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the equivalent of render(test) in render(:partial=> "test" ...)?

I believe that it's render(:partial=>"test", :collection=> test), but this doesn't seem to be working for my application.

`render(test)` works correctly, but `render(:partial=>"test", :collection=> test)` doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It is on the same view folder otherwise specify "folder/filename"

Comment: Yes, it's in the same folder.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work" ? Is there an error? Have you tried renaming the collection variable to something other than `test`? What is the output?

Comment: In my partial "_test.html.erb", I added a test message (a hello world).  When I call the partial with render(test), the message appears on my page.  When I try to call the partial with render(:partial=>"test", :collection=> test), the message doesn't appear.  The page loads without errors, but it doesn't have the test message I put in the partial.

Answer (score 2):

When you call

```
render partial: "test", collection: test
```

there is an expectation that

- You have a file named `_test.html.erb` in the same directory as the view template the `render` is called from
- The `:collection` value is enumerable
- In `_test.html.erb` you use a `test` variable to work with an item from the `test` collection

The `test` variable in the partial file is named `test` after the `_test.html.erb` filename, **not** the collection variable `test` or it's model instance class name.

I suggest reading the [Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections) guide on **Rendering Collections**.

Comment: thanks for your help.  I edited my question to make it clearer.  Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

the reason it wasn't working was that it didn't need a collection parameter; in the end, this was what worked:

```
render(:partial=>"test", :locals=> {:test=> test})
```

Comment: This means `test` is not in fact an enumberable. Glad you got it sorted out.